# Android SQLiteException: near "0": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am quite new to SQLite, and I have a syntax error that I can't point out.. I feel like I already tried everything..

there's my code :

```
String favorites = "CREATE TABLE " + AvailoContract.Favorites.TABLE_NAME
            + "(" + AvailoContract.Favorites._ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
            + AvailoContract.Favorites.ID + " TEXT ,"
            + AvailoContract.Favorites.ROOTUID + " TEXT ,"
            + AvailoContract.Favorites.FILEKEY + " TEXT ,"
            + AvailoContract.Favorites.NAME + " TEXT ,"
            + AvailoContract.Favorites.SUBJECT + " TEXT ,"
            + AvailoContract.Favorites.DESCRIPTION + " TEXT ,"
            + AvailoContract.Favorites.BODY + " TEXT ,"
            + AvailoContract.Favorites.ACCOUNTID + " TEXT ,"
            + AvailoContract.Favorites.DBMODIFIEDTIME + " INTEGER " + ")";
    db.execSQL(favorites);
```

if I remove the INTEGER line it works just fine.
somewhere in the integer line something is wrong.
that's the integer definition in the contract class :

```
public final static long DBMODIFIEDTIME = 0;
```

the error I get :

```
01-25 16:45:11.312  29510-29536/com.appus.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-114217
Process: com.appus.app, PID: 29510
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "0": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE favorites(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,id TEXT ,rootUid TEXT ,fileKey TEXT ,name TEXT ,subject TEXT ,description TEXT ,body TEXT ,accountId TEXT ,false TEXT ,0 INTEGER )
```

thanks all for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the columns `AvailoContract.Favorites.ACCOUNTID` and `AvailoContract.Favorites.DBMODIFIEDTIME`

Based on the error you get, I don't think `false` and `0` can be names of columns.

Answer (score 0):

`AvailoContract.Favorites.DBMODIFIEDTIME` is a Long type constant, you need it to be a String, it's a name for the table column, not the value.
Note that you are CREATING a table, not inserting values into it.